# extend or inherit an object prototypes when calling a native prototype method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I've been reading [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and somewhere it sais :

> **Bad practice: Extension of native prototypes**
>
> One mis-feature that is often used is to extend Object.prototype or
>   one of the other built-in prototypes.
>
> This technique is called monkey patching and breaks encapsulation.
>   While used by popular frameworks such as Prototype.js, there is still
>   no good reason for cluttering built-in types with additional
>   non-standard functionality.
>
> The only good reason for extending a built-in prototype is to backport
>   the features of newer JavaScript engines; for example Array.forEach,
>   etc.

What I'm trying to do in a real example is an angular service to handle http requests that returns a simple object instance with few attributes and 2 methods `findAll()` and `findOne(id)` that I'll use one of them (and only once) in my ui-router's resolve method :

```js
resolve: {
    Resource: 'Resource',
    allImages: function(Resource) {
      var images = new Resource('images');
      return images.findAll();
    },
    singleImage: function(Resource) {
      var image = new Resource('images');
      return image.findOne(4);
    }
},
```

Depending on which of the 2 methods I'll call, I'm trying to extend (or even replace) the whole instance `Resource` with another predefined one `Item` or `Collection` where each have its own structure and methods so in my Controller I can do stuffs like :

```js
if (allImages.existNext()) allImages.nextPage();

var currentPage = allImages.meta.currentPage,
    collection = allImages.data;

singleImage.url = 'abc';
singleImage.save();
```

Now, the only working solution I found so far (represented by a minimal example that have nothing to do with http requests) is this :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('Animal', Animal);

function Animal() {

    var Cat = function() {
        this.prefferedFood = 'fish';
    };

    Cat.prototype.sayMiau = function() {
        console.log('Miau!')
    };

    var Dog = function(name) {
        this.dogName = name;
    };

    Dog.prototype.sayGrr = function() {
        console.log('Grrr!')
    };

    function Animal(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    Animal.prototype = {
        makeItCat: function() {},
        makeItDog: function(name) {
           Dog.call(this, name);
           this.__proto__ = Dog.prototype;
        },
    };

    return Animal;
}
```

So inside Controller I can do:

```js
var Dan = new Animal(7);
Dan.makeItDog('Dan');
Console.log(Dan.age); // outputs "7"
Console.log(Dan.dogName); // outputs "Dan"
Dan.sayGrr(); // outputs "Grrr!"
```

And it works as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tunecino/rk23d9t3/15/).

### The Question is :

Is that Correct? I'm not breaking the way how **Object.prototype** should work or losing the performance gain it should provide? Is there a better way to do it? like maybe using `angular.extend` or maybe not extending (or replacing) prototype at all and using something like this instead:

```js
var Dog = function(name) {
    this.dogName = name;
    this.sayGrr = function(string) {
      console.log('Grrr!')
    }
};
...
Animal.prototype = {
    makeItCat: function() {},
    makeItDog: function(name) {
      Dog.call(this, name);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you are doing it may work. I'm not sure about the factory implementation you did. I did something similar once that may help:

**View working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsotobianco/fun6ya7g/)**

This is your code with slight edits:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('AnimalFactory', AnimalFactory);

function AnimalFactory() {

  // This is the main class
  var Animal = function(age, fullName) {

    this.age = age;
    this.fullName = fullName;

    this.eat = function() {
      console.log('I am eating');
    };

  };

  // Dog should inherit from Animal 
  var Dog = function(age, fullName) {

    // Calling the animal constructor
    Animal.call(this, age, fullName);

    // Augmenting object adding a new method
    this.bark = function() {
      console.log('I am ' + this.fullName + ' and I bark Woof woof');
    };
  };

  // Setting the Dog prototype to Animal
  Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal);

  var Cat = function(age, fullName) {

    // Calling the animal constructor
    Animal.call(this, age, fullName);

    // Augmenting object adding a new method
    this.meow = function() {
      console.log('I am ' + this.fullName + ' and I meow');
    };
  };

  // Setting the Cat prototype to Animal
  Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal);

  function createDog(age, fullName) {
    return new Dog(age, fullName);
  }

  function createCat(age, fullName) {
    return new Cat(age, fullName);
  }

  // Interface returned to use factory
  return {
    createDog: createDog,
    createCat: createCat
  };
}

function MyCtrl($scope, AnimalFactory) {

  var dan = AnimalFactory.createDog(7, 'Dan');
  dan.bark();

  console.log(dan);

  $scope.dan = dan;
}
```

I think the above code has a cleaner implementation of prototypes inheritance between your classes. Let me know what you think so we can improve it.

Comment: nice answer. I didn't try it yet in my real example but after reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) I'm pretty sure it wasn't a good idea to directly set `__proto__`. designing inheritance layouts and chaining prototypes at the start when the service is first called then using the `new` keyword to return an instance when needed should be a much cleaner solution than mine. thanks for sharing it !

Comment: Exactly. I think you example may work but this solution provides a cleaner approach. I'm more than glad to help you @salemOuerdani. Greetings!